# Python pandas: Getting the locations of a value in dataframe

Tags: python, search, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   'a' 'b'
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   0   1
3   0   1
```

Is there a way I could get the index/column values for which a specific value exists? For example, something akin to the following:

```
values = df.search(1)
```

would have `values = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind working with a NumPy array with the first column expressing the index location and the second column expressing the *index* of the column name as it resides in `df.columns`, then it's very short:

```
In [11]: np.argwhere(df)
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```

If you want to format this into the list of tuples with actual column names, you can further do:

```
In [12]: [(x, df.columns[y]) for x,y in np.argwhere(df)]
Out[12]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
```

You can use this same approach with logical expressions inside of `np.argwhere`, so for example say you have this DataFrame of some random data:

```
In [13]: dfrm
Out[13]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.382531  0.287066  0.345749
1  0.725201  0.450656  0.336720
2  0.146883  0.266518  0.011339
3  0.111154  0.190367  0.275750
4  0.757144  0.283361  0.736129
5  0.039405  0.643290  0.383777
6  0.632230  0.434664  0.094089
7  0.658512  0.368150  0.433340
8  0.062180  0.523572  0.505400
9  0.287539  0.899436  0.194938

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

Then you could do this for example:

```
In [14]: [(x, dfrm.columns[y]) for x,y in np.argwhere(dfrm > 0.8)]
Out[14]: [(9, 'B')]
```

As a search function, it can be defined like this:

```
def search(df, df_condition):
    return [(x, df.columns[y]) for x,y in np.argwhere(df_condition(df))]
```

For example:

```
In [17]: search(dfrm, lambda x: x > 0.8)
Out[17]: [(9, 'B')]

In [18]: search(df, lambda x: x == 1)
Out[18]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. This would be good if I was using `numpy` instead of `pandas`.

Comment: @hlin117 Do notice that in my example, the NumPy functions are directly operating on pandas DataFrame objects. It's a bit of a fallacy to pretend like you are only using either pandas or NumPy. If you're using pandas, you are therefore also using NumPy, and nowadays the reverse is almost always true as well. In fact, for a DataFrame `df`, `df.values` returns a `numpy.ndarray` -- highlighting that NumPy is a dependency of pandas. I urge you not to think of it in terms of "pandas vs. numpy" because using NumPy functions is often waaaaay better than using pandas functions.

Answer (score 27):

```
df[df == 1].stack().index.tolist()
```

yields

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the short answer. Can you explain what your code is doing, with the `df.stack()` manipulations?

Comment: `df.stack()` creates a multiindex. So instead of rows and columns, you only have rows that are doubly indexed. So when you call the `tolist()` method on the index you then get 2-tuples.

Comment: Very simple and elegant answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was playing with some other ways of doing this the other week... this trumps all of them... good use of `.stack()`... bookmarked and added to my useful snippets directory... +1 and thanks very much @Alex

Comment: I had been looking for how to find the location of values within a pandas DataFrame for so long today - so glad I found this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use pd.melt + some other munging.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0,0],
                    'b':[0,0,1,1]})

df1 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['index'])
df1 = df1[df1['value'] == 1]
locations = zip(df1['index'],df1['variable'])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
```